# John has "persuaded" me to keep off alcohol

Tags: present-perfect, present-perfect-progressive

> John has persuaded me to keep off alcohol many times in the past year, but I haven't decided yet to give it up.

In the sentence presented above, is persuade used correctly? I don't think so, because *"John has persuaded me"* means he's succeeded in persuading me to keep off alcohol.

In order to make it correct, I think I should change it to

> John has been persuading me to keep off alcohol in the past year, but I haven't decided yet to give it up.

Comment: You are correct. You could also use _has been trying to persuade_.

Comment: @KateBunting - one thing that grates on my British ear is hearing people say that someone 'convinced' someone else to do something, when I would prefer to use 'persuade'.

Comment: I think colloquial ***to talk someone out of** [doing something]* more easily carries the sense of ***on one / several occasions*** without necessarily implying any permanent behaviour change. And there's no question but that ***John has talked me out of getting drunk many times in the past year*** only implies ***on certain occasions*** (it's ambiguous whether speaker got drunk on *other* occasions, but it's kinda implied that he *will* get drunk again in the future unless John really doubles down on his role here).